# Find the interquartile range, that is, $\phi_{0.75} - \phi_{0.25}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

**$F(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & : y \lt 0\\
cy^3 & : 0 \le y \le 2\\
1 - \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right) &: y \ge 2
\end{array}
\right.$**

**1) Find c**

**2) Find the density function (pdf) of Y**

**3) Find the interquartile range, that is, $\phi_{0.75} - \phi_{0.25}$**

*What I have done so far:*

a) For this, I took the limits from both sides around 2. So:
$$\lim_{y\to2^{-}} F(y) =\lim_{y\to2^{-}} cy^3  = 8c$$
and
$$\lim_{y\to2^{+}} F(y) =\lim_{y\to2^{+}} 1- \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)  = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$$

Then setting those two equal, I got $c = \left(\frac{3}{32}\right)$

b) For this part, I believe I was supposed to just take the derivative at each place. So I got:

**$f(y) = F'(y)= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & : y \lt 0\\
\left(\frac{9}{32}\right)y^2 & : 0 \le y \le 2\\
\left(\frac{2}{y^3}\right) &: y \ge 2
\end{array}
\right.$**

c) For this part, I'm not really sure how to go about this yet. I am struggling to understand how to set these equations up and how to solve them. I know that I do need to solve $\phi_{0.75}$ and $\phi_{0.25}$. As far as I understand, I can start with the general formula $P(Y \le \phi_{p}) = F(\phi_{p}) \ge p$. I'm not sure how to pick the correct piece of the CDF to plug into for both $p=0.75$ and $p=0.25$ to solve that equation though.

Comment: @Masacroso Whoops, that is a mistake. Those are supposed to be "y". Let me fix that real quick.

Comment: a) and b) seems right to me. For c) you need first found the part of the function $F$ where $F(x)=0.25$ and $F(x)=0.75$ lie, and after equate to find for each case the value of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median $M$ is defined by a CDF equal to $1/2$. So you get

$$\frac{3}{32} y^3=\frac{1}{2} $$
$$M=2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Similarly, you get the $q_1$ and $q_3$ values of the IQR by setting

$$\frac{3}{32} y^3=\frac{1}{4} $$
$$q_1=\frac{2}{ \sqrt[3]{3}}$$

and

$$\frac{3}{32} y^3=\frac{3}{4} $$
$$q_3=2$$

Note that this last value was already known from your calculations.

So the IQR $\displaystyle \{ q_1,q_3\}= \left\{ \frac{2}{    \sqrt[3]{3}   },2  \right\}$